# jquery form ajax

Tags: jquery

I have this form

```
<form name="send" id="myform>
 <input type="text" name="data"  id="input_field">
 <input type="checkbox" value="true" id="my_check">
</form>
```

I`m sending the information from this form via ajax:

```
$(function() {
    $.post('url.php', {
        data : $('#input_field').val(),
        check : $('#my_check').val(),
        function() {}
});
```

The problem is that I can`t figure out how to send the form only with #input_field value if #my_check is not checked ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You syntax is incorrect, `data` is an object which contains all data inside of the form for example:

```
data: {
    text: $('#input_field').val(),
    check: $('#my_check').val()
}
```

Putting that aside, if you use jQuery's built in [`serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method to create that data object for you it will ignore non "successful controls", and this includes unckecked checkboxes:

```
$(function() {
    $.post('url.php', $('from#myfrom').serialize(), function() {
        // callback
    });
});
```

See the [W3C definition of successful controls](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2) form more information.

Comment: This would error, look closely at the code...you're trying to pass a function as an object label instead of `{data : $('from#myfrom').serialize()` you just need `$('from#myfrom').serialize()`.